# How to automatically select a word on a page with css

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I am using revealjs and want some words to be automatically selected/highlighted on my slides.

So I defined this class:

```
.force-select {  
  -webkit-user-select: all;  /* Chrome 49+ */
  -moz-user-select: all;     /* Firefox 43+ */
  -ms-user-select: all;      /* No support yet */
  user-select: all;          /* Likely future */   
}
```

Then using it like `<span class="force-select"> word </span>` 
But unless I click on the word it is not getting auto-selected.

Any ideas how auto-select that?

Comment: read doc it gets highlight on one click (instead double click):https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_user-select.asp (and one click works for me)

Comment: Of course it doesn’t get auto-selected … what you are doing here is apply formatting to elements that _are_ selected, but it doesn’t automagically work in the other direction, as in that it would _select_ any elements on its own. Selecting those elements is probably not what you want to begin with, but rather highlighting only … so apply whatever actual formatting you want “highlighted” items to have using this rule, and then set/remove the class dynamically on your elements as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`user-select: all;`  property is used to 'Text selection' is made with one
 click instead of a double-click and `user-select:` has no value for auto 
 selection or highlighted 'word'